# AWS ELB Redirect HTTP to HTTPS without index.php

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to host my website with Load Balancer over some EC2 instances.

I am using OctoberCMS (a flavour of laravel as a framework)

I have setup SSL Certificate over my ELB via AWS Certificate Manager and all is working fine.

But there is a problem.

I want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

According to AWS, I got a small .htaccess snippet to do the job:

```
Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

However, when a user gets to `http://mywebsitesite.com` it takes them to `https://mywebsitesite.com/index.php` hence they start browsing in the manner of `https://mywebsitesite.com/index.php/someresource`.

Also if you go to `http://mywebsitesite.com/someresource`, you are redirected back to `https://mywebsitesite.com/index.php`.

This is not a good experience and I know someone must have encountered this before and is able to redirect to resource properly and remove the index.php

My ELB listener is configured by default to 80 --> 80 and 443 --> 80

Note: I am not encountering a redirect loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface this answer with saying that this is code from the Tomcat Elastic Beanstalk but I believe that it should still work.

I had in my configuration code file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R,L]
```

This was part of a .ebextensions file that configured the Apache proxy which, in my case, was in front of Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line in .htaccess to hide the index.php from the url after the redirect configuration.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```